# Codes for multiagent reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I want to study some fundamental multiagent reinforcement algorithms like team-Q, distributed-Q as well as Frequency Maximum Q-value (FMQ), but I can't find the corresponding source codes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many publications about these methods, if you search well you can find the (psuedo) code for the algorithms, for example:

- Distributed Q-Learning: [Distributed Q-Learning for Dynamically Decoupled Systems](https://www.groundai.com/project/distributed-q-learning-for-dynamically-decoupled-systems/#section_9);
- FMQ: [A study of FMQ heuristic in cooperative multi-agent
  games.](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00342324/document);
- Team Q-Learning: [Value-function reinforcement learning in Markov games](http://www.sts.rpi.edu/%7Ersun/si-mal/article3.pdf) (section 5.2).